# How to restart cmd.exe on windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

To exit cmd you type exit.

How do you restart the cmd prompt? Essentially, close and open the CMD.exe application.

Or is there something in powershell to accomplish this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Can you not use another session from within the current session?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is it just to blank out the console? In that case just use `cls` (clear screen).

Comment: No close the cmd and open it back up.

Comment: Use this command: `start /b&exit`.

Comment: doesn't work. is that a typo? cuz i did it word for word.

Comment: How exactly it does not work?

Comment: PetSerAl's solution works for me.  Note that it doesn't close and reopen the console window, but it does restart the cmd.exe process.  If you want the console window to close and reopen too, leave out the `/b` flag.

Answer (score 0):

from Window's "start" menu, do
Start -> Run -> cmd